# What does/can 'on the ground' mean?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

Can 'on the ground' mean "inside the building"?

> However we have strong grounds to believe Ukrainian forces deliberately targeted the hospital for attack as they believed—falsely—that there were insurgents **on the ground**.

(from [here](https://www.hrw.org/news/2014/07/18/ukraine-letter-president-poroshenko-military-operations-luhansk-and-donetsk))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's commonly used to mean "present."  An older phrase meaning roughly the same thing is "on the scene."  I have seen more than one essay on writing style that noted that "on the ground" can usually be deleted with no change in meaning but an improvement in the result.  Here, instead of deleting it altogether, you might replace it with one of the options already mentioned or simply with "there."

Comment: "Present" where?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev in this example, present inside or nearby the hospital.  Another word that could be used instead is "there."

Answer (score -3):

I think that use is an error. It should have said "**on the grounds**", with an "**s**". That would mean the same as "on the premises". In this example, that would mean there were insurgents within the hospital or on the  land where the hospital is situated.

The phrase "**on the ground**" is used also, but in talking about insurgents, it would mean that they came in by air, and were now actually on the surface of the earth in the area.

After comments, I am retracting the claim that "on the ground" means they arrived by air. What I continue to assert is that "on the ground" doesn't mean "located within a small area", but their general existence in a wide area, which would not be a justification for an attack on a localized installation like a hospital. I believe the simplest explanation is a typo for "on the grounds".

Comment: I am not sure it is an error. I have heard military jargon, *e.g.* "boots on the ground" to mean "soldiers in the area," without meaning that the troops arrived by air. I doubt it is possible to deduce what the author meant or intended to write more clearly than that there was a mistaken belief that insurgents were in or near the hospital.

Comment: @JeffMorrow I think "boots on the ground" means a recent arrival of troops in a general area, by whatever means. A hospital is a pretty localized area, and justification for attacking it would require suspicion that "insurgents were on the grounds." So I'll disagree with you on this.

Comment: [on the ground](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+ground) *In or at a location where the real work or action is happening, as opposed to observing or directing something from a distance.*

Comment: It could be a typo, because further along in the article it says *and the attack lasted no longer than 10 minutes, with a total of nine shells hitting the hospital and its grounds.* but “it would mean they came from the air” makes no sense at all.

Comment: As @ColleenV's comment says, "boots on the ground" says nothing about the time of arrival.  It merely indicates physical presence as opposed to remote presence through aircraft, artillery, telescopes, satellites, spies, etc.

Comment: I disagree: "in the grounds", if that is what were meant, would be correct here; "on the grounds" is idiomatically unnatural. "on the ground" is completely idiomatically correct -- it just means "present" with military overtones.

Comment: @PrimeMover Do you have an example of a native speaker writing “in the grounds” to mean located within the boundaries of a campus? Is it a transatlantic difference?

Comment: @ColleenV sorry, I haven't been able to. It may be more natural to say "within the grounds", as in "No smoking within the hospital grounds" or something, but I fear that I am speaking only from my own understanding as a native of Britain. And now I'm not too sure of my grounds (pun intended).

Comment: @ColleenV  "Boots on the ground" is more specific than "on the ground". Oxford Lexico defines it as "informal - Ground troops who are on active service in a military operation.", so, that they arrived by air is not implied, but that they got there from somewhere else, be it air, ship, train, or military ground vehicles, is implied. So, "boots on the ground" doesn't apply to this example.

Comment: @PrimeMover Both "on the grounds" and  "in the grounds" are found referring to being present on the premises of anything from a house to a mansion to a school to a church. So, I don't think either is unnatural, though "on the grounds" is how I would say it. If you search for the phrase at Google books, even after you eliminate all the meanings like "for the reason", there are plenty of them left meaning "premises" or "territory".

Comment: The phrase “boots on the ground” is nowhere to be found in anything I wrote or in the article. I am not following your point at all. The idiom “on the ground” is not restricted to the military and has nothing to do with how the resource you have “on the ground” arrived there.

Comment: @ColleenV That phrase was in another comment, just before yours, and I thought you were commenting on that. Sorry I missed your point. I still think "on the ground" is a mistake in the original article, for the reason that I have edited into my answer.